# Form Action not work, the exist address shows "Page Not Found"

Tags: php

Hi I am using WP to create web site, and I am using the following code

```
        <?php
        while ($set1 = mysqli_fetch_array($drink))
            {
            echo "<form action = 'check-out-process' method = 'post'>Product: ".$set1['P_name']."     ";
            echo "In Stock: ".$set1['P_qty']."<br/><br/>";
            echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "' .$set1['P_id']. '">';
            echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "name" value = "' .$set1['P_name']. '">';
            echo "Quantity: <input type='text' name='qty'><br/><input type = 'submit' value = 'SUBMIT'/></form>";
            }
        ?>
```

And I have create a child page under this page, using the url "/check-out-process".

The problem is, when I click submit, it always turns to "Page not Found". Only after I add a "/" after the url, it turns the check-out-process page.

Could someone tells me how to fix it?

### I just figure out, I shouldnt use   name = "name"

Thanks for helping guys, it solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
.. echo "<form action = 'check-out-process/check-out-process.php' ...
```

action attribute must be refer to a file, not a folder.

Comment: hi thanks so helping, i just figure out, i shouldnt use name = "name" :-)  And I think the action attribute could be without the extension, bc it works here :-)   Anyway, thanks for helping