# PHP process page does not work

Tags: php

Hi guys my process page does not work, my code is

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['item_id'];
$qty = $_POST['item_qty'];
$name = $_POST['item_name'];

$con = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "name", "password", "db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql = "INSERT INTO Temp (id, qty, name)
VALUES
('$_POST[id]', '$_POST[qty]', '$_POST[name]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

header('Location: http://url.com/');

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Should be all correct, just copy from w3school,
The problem is, the db only get 0,

ie. my $id is 4, $qty is 12, $name is "Hello", after the process page, the table only get two 0s in id and qty, name is void.

The values should be processed to this process page successfully, bc I have tried

```
echo $id, $qty, $name;
```

All are the same as I typed in before.

Could anyone help me? thanks :-)

Comment: You're using `$_POST[id]', '$_POST[qty]', '$_POST[name]`..should they not have `item_` in front of `id,qty,name`?

Comment: you should consider prepared statements in mysqli. you're currently open to injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
INSERT INTO Temp (id, qty, name) VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$_POST[qty]', '$_POST[name]')";
```

should be:

```
INSERT INTO Temp (id, qty, name) VALUES ('$id', '$qty', '$name')";
```

If the `form` is from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713914/form-action-not-work-the-exist-address-shows-page-not-found/15713975), you dont need:

```
$id = $_POST['item_id'];
$qty = $_POST['item_qty'];
$name = $_POST['item_name'];
```

Comment: oh thanks, it works :-), probably I made some stupid mistake before bc I tried it before

Answer (score 0):

I agree it looks like you left out item_. You might want to sanitize your data first.

```
$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['item_id']);
$qty=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['item_qty']);
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Temp (id, qty, name)
VALUES ('$id', '$qty', '$name')";
```